# How can I stabilize my background Image in CSS

Tags: html, css

I just made my navigation section. and I wanna make original body of site. but When I'm adding background Image. Image goes on navbar. sorry for my bad English but if you don't get my mean. I added details for you. Note: My problem is resizing not scroll down
Here's HTML :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Noto+Serif:ital@1&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
        <title>ElectroLand</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <!--Navbar Starts ====================================== -->
        <header>     
            <div class="container">
                    <nav>
                        <div class="logo"><img src="/img/logo.png"></div>
                        <div class="nav-list">
                            <ul class="nav-item"><li><a href="#">Home</a></li></ul>
                            <ul class="nav-item"><li><a href="#">Products</a></li></ul>
                            <ul class="nav-item"><li><a href="#">About</a></li></ul>
                            <div class="hamburger" onclick="clk()" id="burger">
                                <div id="line1"></div>
                                <div id="line2"></div>
                                <div id="line3"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </nav>
               </div>
               <div class="sidemenu" id="sdmenu">
                <div class="side-items">
                    <ul class="side-item"><li><a href="#">Home</a></li></ul>
                    <ul class="side-item"><li><a href="#">Products</a></li></ul>
                    <ul class="side-item"><li><a href="#">About</a></li></ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
        <script src="/func.js"></script>
    <!--Navbar End===========================================-->
    <div class="mid-section">
        
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here's CSS:

```
/* Navbar starts ===============================================================================*/
body{
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.container{
    width: 100%;
    height:10vh;
    position: relative;
    background-color: rgb(39, 44, 52);
}
.logo{
    position: absolute;
    padding:0.6%;
    padding-top: 0.2%;
    
}
.nav-list{  
    font-family: 'Noto Serif', serif;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    top: 1%;
    display: flex;
    padding:1.0%;
}
.nav-list a{
    margin: 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #80e560;
    transition: color 400ms ease-in-out;
}
.nav-list a:hover{
    color: #a8fbfc;
}
.nav-list ul{
    list-style-type: none;
}
.hamburger{
position: relative;
cursor: pointer;
display: none;
-moz-transform-origin: 20px;
-ms-transform-origin: 20px;
-o-transform-origin: 20px;
-webkit-transform-origin: 20px;
transform-origin: 20px;
transition: width 800ms ease-in-out;
transition: height 800ms ease-in-out;

}
.hamburger div{
    width: 20px;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: #80e560;
    margin: 3px;
    margin-left: 50%;
    transition: transform 210ms ease-in-out;
}
.sidemenu{
   position: absolute;
   right: 0px;
   width: 40%;
   height: 100%;
   width: 20%;
   background-color: rgb(39, 44, 52);
   transform:translateX(100%);
   transition:transform 500ms;
   
}
.side-items{
    height:80%;
    justify-content:space-between;
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    font-family: 'Noto Serif', serif;
    align-items : space-between;
}
.side-item{
    list-style-type: none;
}
.side-item a{
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: color 500ms ease-in-out;
}
.side-item a:hover{color:#80e560;}
@media screen and (max-width:1500px){
    .logo{padding-top: 0.3%;}
}
@media screen and (max-width:768px){
    .nav-item{
        display: none;
    }
    .hamburger{
        display:inline;
        bottom: 12px;
        right: 35px;
    }
    .side-items{
        right: 20%;
    }
    .nav-list{
        padding: 40px;
    }
    .container{
        height: 10vh;
    }
    .logo{padding-top: 2%;}

}
@media screen and (max-width:568px){
    .hamburger{
        right: 50%;
    }
    .side-items{
        right: 20%;
        font-size: 12px;
    }
    .container{
        height: 11vh;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width:280px)
{     
     .side-items{
         right: 9%;
     }
     .hamburger{
         right: 6%;
     }
}

/* Navbar Ends ========================================================================*/
.mid-section{
background-image: url(/img/background.jpg);
width: 1920px;
height: 1080px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
display: block;
position: relative;
}
```

I also made hamburger menu so don't care about it. it will be OK if I fix my background problem, for more detail I added this picture to show the awkward result. I just don't want this happening.

[image: I wanna make my background Image stable]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to change the height of container.

```css
body{
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.container{
    width: 100%;
    height:78px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: rgb(39, 44, 52);
}
.logo{
    position: absolute;
    padding:0.6%;
    padding-top: 0.2%;
    
}
.nav-list{  
    font-family: 'Noto Serif', serif;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    top: 1%;
    display: flex;
    padding:1.0%;
}
.nav-list a{
    margin: 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #80e560;
    transition: color 400ms ease-in-out;
}
.nav-list a:hover{
    color: #a8fbfc;
}
.nav-list ul{
    list-style-type: none;
}
.hamburger{
position: relative;
cursor: pointer;
display: none;
-moz-transform-origin: 20px;
-ms-transform-origin: 20px;
-o-transform-origin: 20px;
-webkit-transform-origin: 20px;
transform-origin: 20px;
transition: width 800ms ease-in-out;
transition: height 800ms ease-in-out;

}
.hamburger div{
    width: 20px;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: #80e560;
    margin: 3px;
    margin-left: 50%;
    transition: transform 210ms ease-in-out;
}
.sidemenu{
   position: absolute;
   right: 0px;
   width: 40%;
   height: 100%;
   width: 20%;
   background-color: rgb(39, 44, 52);
   transform:translateX(100%);
   transition:transform 500ms;
   
}
.side-items{
    height:80%;
    justify-content:space-between;
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    font-family: 'Noto Serif', serif;
    align-items : space-between;
}
.side-item{
    list-style-type: none;
}
.side-item a{
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: color 500ms ease-in-out;
}
.side-item a:hover{color:#80e560;}
@media screen and (max-width:1500px){
    .logo{padding-top: 0.3%;}
}
@media screen and (max-width:768px){
    .nav-item{
        display: none;
    }
    .hamburger{
        display:inline;
        bottom: 12px;
        right: 35px;
    }
    .side-items{
        right: 20%;
    }
    .nav-list{
        padding: 40px;
    }
    .container{
        height: 89px;
    }
    .logo{padding-top: 2%;}

}
@media screen and (max-width:568px){
    .hamburger{
        right: 50%;
    }
    .side-items{
        right: 20%;
        font-size: 12px;
    }
    .container{
        height: 89px;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width:280px)
{     
     .side-items{
         right: 9%;
     }
     .hamburger{
         right: 6%;
     }
}

.mid-section{
background-image: url(https://www.bigheartsoutdoors.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/Rectangle-1920x1080-Placeholder.png);
width: 1920px;
height: 1080px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
display: block;
position: relative;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Noto+Serif:ital@1&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
        <title>ElectroLand</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>     
            <div class="container">
                    <nav>
                        <div class="logo"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/140x100" height=70></div>
                        <div class="nav-list">
                            <ul class="nav-item"><li><a href="#">Home</a></li></ul>
                            <ul class="nav-item"><li><a href="#">Products</a></li></ul>
                            <ul class="nav-item"><li><a href="#">About</a></li></ul>
                            <div class="hamburger" onclick="clk()" id="burger">
                                <div id="line1"></div>
                                <div id="line2"></div>
                                <div id="line3"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </nav>
               </div>
               <div class="sidemenu" id="sdmenu">
                <div class="side-items">
                    <ul class="side-item"><li><a href="#">Home</a></li></ul>
                    <ul class="side-item"><li><a href="#">Products</a></li></ul>
                    <ul class="side-item"><li><a href="#">About</a></li></ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
        <script src="/func.js"></script>
    <div class="mid-section">
        
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using z-index: 1; on the nav bar!!!

Comment: please use position: sticky; with z-index

Comment: try using z-index: 9999; btw which class are you using it in?

Comment: Container class , you can see in html.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the **header** with `sticky`

```
header{
  position:sticky;
  top:0;
  z-index:2;
}
```

```css
/* Navbar starts ===============================================================================*/
body{
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.container{
    width: 100%;
    height:10vh;
    position: relative;
    background-color: rgb(39, 44, 52);
}
.logo{

    
}
.nav-list{  
    font-family: 'Noto Serif', serif;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    top: 1%;
    display: flex;
    padding:1.0%;
}
.nav-list a{
    margin: 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #80e560;
    transition: color 400ms ease-in-out;
}
.nav-list a:hover{
    color: #a8fbfc;
}
.nav-list ul{
    list-style-type: none;
}
.hamburger{
position: relative;
cursor: pointer;
display: none;
-moz-transform-origin: 20px;
-ms-transform-origin: 20px;
-o-transform-origin: 20px;
-webkit-transform-origin: 20px;
transform-origin: 20px;
transition: width 800ms ease-in-out;
transition: height 800ms ease-in-out;

}
.hamburger div{
    width: 20px;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: #80e560;
    margin: 3px;
    margin-left: 50%;
    transition: transform 210ms ease-in-out;
}
.sidemenu{
   position: absolute;
   right: 0px;
   width: 40%;
   height: 100%;
   width: 20%;
   background-color: rgb(39, 44, 52);
   transform:translateX(100%);
   transition:transform 500ms;
   
}
.side-items{
    height:80%;
    justify-content:space-between;
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    font-family: 'Noto Serif', serif;
    align-items : space-between;
}
.side-item{
    list-style-type: none;
}
.side-item a{
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: color 500ms ease-in-out;
}
.side-item a:hover{color:#80e560;}
@media screen and (max-width:1500px){
    .logo{padding-top: 0.3%;}
}
@media screen and (max-width:768px){
    .nav-item{
        display: none;
    }
    .hamburger{
        display:inline;
        bottom: 12px;
        right: 35px;
    }
    .side-items{
        right: 20%;
    }
    .nav-list{
        padding: 40px;
    }
    .container{
        height: 10vh;
    }
    .logo{padding-top: 2%;}

}
@media screen and (max-width:568px){
    .hamburger{
        right: 50%;
    }
    .side-items{
        right: 20%;
        font-size: 12px;
    }
    .container{
        height: 11vh;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width:280px)
{     
     .side-items{
         right: 9%;
     }
     .hamburger{
         right: 6%;
     }
}

/* Navbar Ends ========================================================================*/
.mid-section{
  background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/1920);
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  background-position:center;
  background-size:cover;
}

header{
  position:sticky;
  top:0;
  z-index:2;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Noto+Serif:ital@1&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
        <title>ElectroLand</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <!--Navbar Starts ====================================== -->
        <header>     
            <div class="container">
                    <nav>
                        <div class="logo"><img src="logo.png" width="20px" height="20px"></div>
                        <div class="nav-list">
                            <ul class="nav-item"><li><a href="#">Home</a></li></ul>
                            <ul class="nav-item"><li><a href="#">Products</a></li></ul>
                            <ul class="nav-item"><li><a href="#">About</a></li></ul>
                            <div class="hamburger" onclick="clk()" id="burger">
                                <div id="line1"></div>
                                <div id="line2"></div>
                                <div id="line3"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </nav>
               </div>
               <div class="sidemenu" id="sdmenu">
                <div class="side-items">
                    <ul class="side-item"><li><a href="#">Home</a></li></ul>
                    <ul class="side-item"><li><a href="#">Products</a></li></ul>
                    <ul class="side-item"><li><a href="#">About</a></li></ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
        <script src="/func.js"></script>
    <!--Navbar End===========================================-->
    <div class="mid-section">
        
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I did it but I got same result

Comment: problem is not scroll down. is resizing

Comment: Can you give the exact background image link?

Comment: also you try `background-size:cover` instead of adding width and height in `mid-section` class.

Comment: I still have this problem

Comment: When I using background-size:cover instead of width and height. image disappears

Comment: can you add background img link.

Comment: I forgot , but if you wanna know resolution it's 1920*1080

Comment: you can try `background-position:center; background-size:cover; width: 100vw; height: 100vh;`

Answer (score 0):

You can check by adding following lines of css to your navbar

```
background-position: center;
background-size: cover;
```

Comment: my problem is resizing not scroll down. I tried before but didn't work